# Why would a semiconductor with a fixed bandgap have an absorption curve instead of an absorption spike?

Tags: photons, semiconductor-physics

Wouldn't the semiconductor only be able to accept photons at one wavelength?

Comment: Why not photons with more energy than its bandgap? The extra energy would be lost to phonons.

Comment: That makes sense. Would the phonon be the result of an electron having extra kinetic energy, thus causing a disturbance in the material?

Comment: Consider that even molecules do have broad band absorption. Having bands instead of levels means even more broadening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any valence electron as far as energy is concerned can move to anywhere in the conduction band. These bands are quite broad and so there is a broad range of acceptabel transition energies.

[image: http://www.yambo-code.org/wiki/index.php?title=Silicon]